# Can I transfer my Terraria character from one PC to another?

Tags: terraria

Currently my map server is run on my laptop at home, and my brother and I play via LAN each on his desktop PC.

However, I'd like to transfer my character from the Desktop PC to my laptop in order to play on the go.

Can I do this? Where is the character information saved?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you are playing the Steam version with an Internet connection, you can just let Steam do all that work for you by enabling cloud saving for your character.

[image: Terraria "move to cloud" button]

Otherwise, your characters are stored in:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Terraria/Players`
- Linux: `~/.local/share/Terraria/Players`

However, if you're using Steam cloud saves, the files will be in a different location.

`<Steam directory>/userdata/<Steam3 ID>/105600/remote/players`

To copy a character, you will need both the `.plr` file and the folder that are named like your character. Technically, only the file is necessary, but the folder contains your minimap data.

Comment: Oh man thank you for the question and answer.  I was avoiding playing on my desktop because I had started a new character and it is so hard to go back to wooden utilities!

Comment: Do I also need the .plr.bak file? What is that?

Comment: @Sergio No, which is why I explicitly said you only need the `.plr`. I think it's the previous version of the save file; if the save becomes corrupted for some reason, Terraria tries to load the [backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bak_file "Bak file - Wikipedia"). In any case, it's not needed.

Comment: Cheers guys, good question and answer. :)

Comment: I have actually set up Dropbox between the three computers I play Terraria on.. works out really well :)

Comment: You can also do the same with the world but instead of clicking on the folder that says Players, choose the one that says Worlds.

Comment: thx so much does it work if you email the Plr. file to another pc then get steam oon that or how does that work?

Comment: @MickTick Yes, that should work.

Comment: @Nathan you should ask that as a new question. But anyway, it should work fine for worlds as well

Comment: This answer is no longer correct as of the most recent version of the game. Now all that is necessary is to save your player to the cloud and then any other PC you play on should have access to it (provided you're using the same steam account). I recommend you update your answer with this additional note for the current version.

Comment: @ydobonebi Only the Steam version has cloud saves. Also, not all PCs have a constant Internet connection. That said, I've added it to the top because it's probably the best option for most people - thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 7):

As of version 1.3 ([1.3 Patch Notes](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/1-3-changelog.187600/)), you can save your character via the Steam Cloud service. This can be enabled when creating a character.

Comment: IIRC, you can also switch between saving on the cloud and locally by clicking the cloud icon on the character select screen. I am not 100% sure though, maybe that was only worlds.

Comment: @MrLemon Yes, button works too. Also it works both on chars and worlds.

Comment: @MrLemon Both player and world data is cloud savable. Just make sure you update to the most recent patch (I think 1.3.0.2 or something has a glitch that if you save your char or world to the cloud it will cause the game to crash soon after starting. This was fixed however in the most recent update.