# Can I transfer my Terraria data from one account to another on the same pc on steam?

Tags: terraria

I need someone to help me so if you know how please help me cause I have been playing on the wrong account... Does anyone know if you do tell me please thanks! I want to swap it on the same pc not change the pc I want it on a different account on the saem pc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I transfer my Terraria character from one PC to another?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24478/can-i-transfer-my-terraria-character-from-one-pc-to-another)

Comment: Have you considered putting your reply to Anton in the comments rather than in an edit? It would make the question seem much tidier.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Documents (or your steam file directory), go to "My Games", go to "terraria", and copy+paste the files for chars and worlds onto a flash drive.

Then, move it to another computer's directory and put it in the folder you took it out of.

Comment: Seems like he does NOT want to move it to another computer.

Answer (score 0):

> I need someone to help me so if you know how please help me cause I have been playing on the wrong account...

If you're talking about Steam account, then that is *impossible* as Terraria saves are saved into your user documents, regardless of which Steam account you're using.

If you're talking about user accounts (the one you use to log onto your PC), then that's possible.

---

> Does anyone know if you do tell me please thanks

To move your savefiles from PC to PC, or user to user (assuming Windows), go to your My Documents and look for the `my games` folder.
Inside that folder, you'll find several folders for some of your various games, for example:

[image: %userprofile%/my Games]

Now, copy the `Terraria` folder and move it to another location that is not specific to your account. On Windows, you can simply move it onto another disk (ie. another partition or a USB drive) or into the Public User folder at:

```
C:\Users\Public
```

Now, log onto the account (or place your USB with the `Terraria` save folder into another PC) that you want to move the save to, and simply drop it back into that user's `my Games` folder.

Replace/Delete any existing files and you should then be good to go.

Remember as always, **DO NOT REPLACE OR COPY SAVE FILES WHILE THE GAME IS RUNNING**, or you may risk corruption.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you have to find the terraria folder and make a duplicate of your data. Then move the duplicate to your other account. I'm not sure how to do it, though. I think if you search up "how to downnload a terraria map you might get some instructions on how to get to those folders.

PS this probably was the least helpful answer on this entire website xD

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer. I appreciate you trying to help, but if you're not sure then it's best not to post an answer.