# How can I give my friend one of my world saves in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

Me and my friends play Terraria a lot and we only use one main world and I created it. I am not always on as much as they are and they want to use be able to play when i'm not on. Is there a way that I could send  one of my friends the World Save so they could host it instead??

Comment: Check out this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24478/can-i-transfer-my-terraria-character-from-one-pc-to-another

Comment: I assume you mean PC rather than console?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. This question is asking about transferring a World Save, not a Character Save. They are two separate files.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are on PC, you can go to your file directory and find the "My games" folder (usually in the documents section). Open that, and you will find Terraria. Open that, and there will be a worlds folder. copy the .wld (not the .wld.bak) file for your world and send it to him/her.